# Political terminology or example for a leader making their crime a norm by highlighting an opponent's small mistakes?

Tags: democracy, political-theory, terminology, political-system

Let's say that politician A is a corrupt person. His opponent is a moral guy with an honest reputation. The reputation of politician A is badly affected when a news story breaks about his corruption. Then, he finds a small mistake in his opponent's financial history. He boosts his narrative and mixes his big crimes with the opponent's small crimes, and makes immoral financial facts a norm.

What do we call this act? is there any example in history, or is there a terminology?

Answer (score 4):

This could be viewed as a form of *whataboutism*, in which questions about a legitimate issue are not addressed, but merely deflected by pointing to similar issues elsewhere. When politician A is confronted with questions about his own behavior, he merely points to politician B who has exhibited (at least superficially) similar behavior. This can be especially effective when the two issues are superficially similar, but different in seriousness - when A compares his serious misdeeds to the trifling misdeeds of B, he implicitly suggests that all misdeeds of this nature are equal. Whataboutism is a means of deflecting criticism, and in some cases can be an attempt to normalize serious misdeeds by comparing them to minor misdeeds.

There are many, many examples of whataboutism being employed in modern politics, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Whataboutism.

Comment: I think that this is the better answer within the specific realm of politics.  Whataboutism might be a form of _tu quoque_, but the latter is not a common term in the political world.

Comment: thanks for whataboutisam but tu quoque is even more relevant. it took me hours to search for this terminology. thanks a lot to everyone.

Answer (score 1):

I think this would be an example of *[tu quoque](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tu_quoque)*:

> a discussion technique that intends to discredit the opponent's argument by attacking the opponent's own personal behavior and actions as being inconsistent with their argument, therefore accusing hypocrisy.

Essentially, Politician A is saying "You have no right to criticise me about this when you've done it too", even though their own crimes are measurably worse.

Answer (score 1):

**Tu Quoque**

This attack asserts that the argument must be false simply because the person presenting the advice doesn't consistently follow it herself.

The politician A may be much worse than the politician B or even about the same. Both politicians still have the word to say about each other.

You can read about fallacies [here](https://web.cn.edu/kwheeler/fallacies_list.html).

Answer (score 1):

The pattern is known as [Normalization of Deviance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normalization_of_deviance)

Sociologist Diane Vaughan used the term to describe the social matrix that led to the [Challenger Disaster](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Space_Shuttle_Challenger_disaster).

Briefly:
There is a safety norm that is the 'normal'.  The fringes are by definition far out and abnormal.  A slow creeping shift towards the fringes occurs that:

- is unnoticed because it is slow and gradual
  and yet
- is significant because it has gone on long enough

This new norm is recognized as deviated typically only after deleterious results follow.

In its original form used by Diane Vaughan it described the social frame around tech events like the Space Shuttle disaster.  From there it went on to other situations in governments and corporations.  Today its increasingly used to describe the changes that occur in society at large, especially due to [social media](https://www.newyorker.com/news/daily-comment/facebook-and-the-normalization-of-deviance).

Comment: “Normalisation of corruption” maybe?

Comment: @benjimin Ok if you prefer... NoD is the umbrella term arising in the science/tech fields and having a statistical sense. It has a wide provenance.  Given that corruption is the typical malfeasance of politicians when they practice NoD its likely to be nor. of corruption as you say.  OTOH in the science/tech fields where it originated its more likely to be norm. of negligence or some such. For journalists its likely [normalization of bias](https://www.ted.com/talks/alisa_miller_how_the_news_distorts_our_worldview).

Comment: And for social media which is increasingly dangerous its probably [norm. of misinformation](https://pennypost.org.uk/2020/07/fake-news-the-normalisation-of-misinformation-and-how-you-can-navigate-it/). Or even maybe norm. of normalization!!  Which could be stated more prosaically as throwing science, statistics, math to the winds.  In short different groups practice different forms of malfeasance. Normalization of deviance seems to me like a good generic term for all these. In short while politicians are universally reviled as evil, all these others are no better. Maybe worse